# PHP, Dwoo - Variables

Tags: php, dwoo

I'm trying to convert this to dwoo:

```
foreach($duplicates as $duplicate)
{
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach($column_list as $column)
    {
        if(@$duplicate{$column . "_diff"} == 1)
        {
            $id_is_different = '';
            echo "<td style=\"background: #333333\" >". $duplicate{$column} ."</td>\n";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<td>" . $duplicate{$column} ."</td>\n";
        }
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

I have this:

```
{foreach $duplicates duplicate}
<tr>
    {foreach $column_list column}
    <td{if $duplicate.$column.'_diff' == 1} style="background: #333"{/if}>{$duplicate.$column}</td>
    {/foreach}
</tr>            
{/foreach}
```

With the exception of: .$column.'_diff' on the 4th line, it works perfectly. any idea how i can add the suffix to the variable with dwoo?!?!

Thanks!

**EDIT**

I probably should have explained better.

Basically, what I'm doing is grabbing a list of column names from a mysql table, $column_list(using "SHOW COLUMNS FROM..."). Then doing another query to select the data, in that query, i'm matching data in each column to another table and adding a column with a prefix of "_diff" so if i have a column named "name" i also have a column "name_diff"(these columns are not in $column_list) that has a value of either 1 or 0. the 1 or 0 just signify weather or not the data matched in the other table. anyhow, The number of columns and column names are always changing so I can't really use any column names in the code. so....

with dwoo, {$duplicate.$column} would be something like $duplicate['name']; and what i'm trying to do is dynamically add the suffix "_diff" so i can change the background color of the cell... I know that was super confusing! I'm really bad at explaining things!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid the only solution for now is to do the following :

```
{foreach $duplicates duplicate}
<tr>
    {foreach $column_list column}
        {$diffcol = cat($column '_diff')}
        <td{if $duplicate.$diffcol == 1} style="background: #333"{/if}>{$duplicate.$column}</td>
    {/foreach}
</tr>            
{/foreach}
```

Comment: hey its better than have a view with php all over when the rest of them are done with dwoo! Thanks for the response, you can just ignore my post on the dwoo forum!

Answer (score 0):

**try this**

```
{foreach $column_list column}
    <td{if $duplicate.$column.last == 1} style="background: #333"{/if}>{$duplicate.$column}</td>
    {/foreach}
```